# ASP Button hover area is inconsistent with image

Tags: css, button, hover

The hover works, but only on certain parts of the button image or outside the button image.  Also, the hover doesn't work if the arrow enters the button from above.

Any ideas?

```
.buttonSearch{
display: block;
background:   url("../Images/btn Search.JPG") no-repeat top;
height: 40px;
width:100px;
border:1px solid #7AB800;
border-width:0px;
margin-left: 210px;}



.buttonSearch:hover
{display: block;
    background: transparent url("../Images/btn Search Click2.JPG") no-repeat top;
    height: 40px;
    width:100px;
    border:none 0 transparent;
   border-width:0px;
   margin-left: 210px;
```

---

ASP page:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:Panel ID="p" runat="server" DefaultButton="butName">
<br />
<br />

<asp:Label ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoComplete="Off" CssClass="display-labelsearch" Text="Last Name: " />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="display-fieldsearch" MaxLength="100" ToolTip="Please enter a Provider last name."></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="txtName_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" 
        runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtName" WatermarkText="Type Last Name Here"  WatermarkCssClass="watermarked">
        </cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
        <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="txtName" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetNames" 
        UseContextKey="True">
        </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="butName" runat="server" onclick="tbSearchbutton" CssClass="buttonSearch" />




 <asp:GridView ID="gvProvLookup" runat="server"
```

AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="ViewProv_RowCommand"  yada yada

Comment: We need to see your rendered HTML too before we can help. CSS is useless without markup.

Comment: We need the *rendered* HTML, not the ASP.NET source.

Comment: Would it help to use an [ImageButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx) instead of a Button?

Answer (score 0):

Something was covering part of the button.  I moved it down a line and it works properly.